# Proper zero divisors of $\mathbb{Z}[S_4]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How to show that a group $\mathbb{Z}[S_4]$ has proper zero divisors? I think I don't understand the definition of multiplication in this ring. Can someone give me a small hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: elements of the ring are functions $f:S_{4}\to \mathbb{Z} $, equivaketly, they are (finite) formal combinatio's of elements of $G$, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z} $, and the multplication extends that of the group "linearly"       $ [(12)+2(234)]×[1+(34)]=(12)+(12)(34)+2(234)+2(32)$

Comment: I'll check it, thanks @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez

Answer (score 2):

Let $G$ be a finite group. Consider the element
$$\sigma = \sum_{g\in G} g$$
Then we have
$$\sigma\cdot \sigma = |G|\cdot \sigma$$
Therefore

$$\sigma( \sigma- |G|\cdot e) = 0$$

If $|G|\ne 1$, neither of the above factors are $0$.

In general you can construct other similar relations using characters of irreducible representations of $G$.

$\bf{Added:}$

As Mariano indicated, $S_4$ and more generally $S_n$ has the property that all its irreducible representations are realizable over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let's see what we can do about zero-divisors in $A[G]$, $A$ a domain.  Let $k$ be the field of fractions of $G$. Now we have an embedding $A[G]\subset k[G]$, so we'll look for zero-divisors in $k[G]$.

Fact: let $g\mapsto (a_{ij}(g))$, $g\mapsto (a'_{kl}(g))$ two  representations of $G$ over $k$ that are irreducible and non-isomorphic. The we (still) have the Schur orthogonality relations

$$\sum_{g \in G} a_{ij}(g) \cdot a'_{kl}(g^{-1}) = 0$$

simply because there are no non-zero intertwiners between these two representations, so

$$\sum_{g\in G} \Lambda(g)\cdot L \cdot \Lambda'(g^{-1}) = 0$$
for every linear map between the two spaces of the representation.

Now, let's see what this implies for elements in $k[G]$. We claim that we have

$$(\sum_{g\in G}  a_{ij}(g)\, g) \cdot (\sum_{g \in G} a'_{kl}(g)\, g ) = 0$$

Indeed, in the above the coefficient of an element $g \in G$ is
$$\sum_{h\in G} a_{ij} (g h) a'_{kl} (h^{-1}) = \sum_{g\in G} \, (\,\sum_s a_{is}(g) a_{sj}(h)\,)\cdot a'_{kl}(h^{-1})$$

Now rearange the sum as a sum of terms of the form
$\sum_{h\in G}  a_{sj}(h) a'_{kl}(h^{-1}) = 0$ hence the whole sum is $0$.

We got ourselves some relations in $k[G]$, so by chasing away denominators, in $A[G]$.

Note that we might want to impose $\operatorname{char} A \not\mid |G|$.